# Aussprache von »wollen«

Tags: pronunciation

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die »ll« in »wollen« ausgesprochen werden sollen. 
Ich habe es manchmal so gehört, dass man beim Aussprechen des Wortes den L-Klang nicht ausspricht, und daher klingt es mir wie: "Wo-en"; zum Beispiel, in Google Translate.

Ist es von dem Dialekt oder der Sprechgeschwindigkeit abhängend?

Comment: Eher von der Qualität des samples in translate...

Comment: Nein, *ll* wird gesprochen, vergleiche [Duden](https://www.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4119015_353368863.mp3).

Comment: @IQV Auch in: [https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/], mit den Stimmen von "Sarah" und "Klara", ist das "ll" kaum hörbar. Vielleicht wird es nur sehr schwach ausgesprochen?

Comment: Im Wort "wollen" höre ich die "l"s immer sehr klar. Aber deutsche Aussprache habe ich im Allgemeinem viel schweriger gefunden, als es in den Sprachschulen gelehrt wird. Besonders die fehlende Konsonante.

Comment: I would not even know how I should pronounce it without a consonant between o and e (especially if the o is supposed to remain short), so there is definitely something there. Whether you hear it as an *l* is a different matter.

Comment: @CarstenS You assume that the "e" is actually pronounced.

Comment: @Uwe, that is what the OP says he hears.

Comment: Ich halte das nur für Gewohnheit, weil die meisten Fragen hier auf Englisch gestellt werden. Außerdem ist es schwierig abzuschätzen, wie weit man auf Deutsch gehen darf, dass der Frager einen noch versteht.

Comment: In welcher Region hast du das "wo-en" gehört? Ich kenne das aus dem Schweizer Sprachraum.

Comment: @sermonionx es war durchaus nicht mit Absicht, aber Du scheinst meinen Kommentar ja lesen gekonnt zu haben.

Comment: The *ll* are very well pronounced, but much, er... thinner than in English or Dutch, so someone used to the thick English or Dutch *ll* (Germans should think of Rudi Carell) might not hear them as such. It takes some time and practice to pronounce (and hear) the L like in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zunächst einmal ist es in der Umgangssprache üblich, dass das /ə/ in der
Endung "-en" entfällt, also zum Beispiel

- "wegen"  /veːgən/ → /veːgn̩/
- "haben"  /hɑːbən/ → /hɑːbn̩/
- "wollen" /vɔlən/  → /vɔln̩/

Danach findet häufig eine Assimilation zwischen dem Konsonanten
vor dem ausgefallenen /ə/ und dem folgenden (jetzt vokalisierten)
/n/ statt.
Der Konsonant vor dem ausgefallenen /ə/ kann dabei schwach werden
und in manchen Dialekten auch ganz ausfallen:

- "wegen"  /veːgən/ → /veːgn̩/ → /veːgŋ̩/ (→ /veːŋ̩/)
- "haben"  /hɑːbən/ → /hɑːbn̩/ → /hɑːbm̩/ (→ /hɑːm̩/ oder /ham/)

Entsprechend kann das /l/ in "wollen" /vɔln̩/ schwach
werden. Ein völliger Ausfall ist selten, kommt aber dialektal
auch vor, besonders dann, wenn bei "wollen wir" noch eine
weitere Assimilation stattfindet:

- "wollen wir" /vɔlən viːɐ̯/ → /vɔln̩ və/ → /vɔɱvə/