# How to pronounce the 't' in 'Saiten'?

Tags: pronunciation

Do I make a clear 't' sound with my tongue or a sort of vague 't' sound with the back of my throat? On forvo the gentleman clearly pronounces the 't' so it sounds like 'Sai-ten' but on other websites I am not hearing properly the 't' sound, it is more like 'Sai(t)-en'. Thanks

Comment: The _t_ should be clearly pronounced.

Comment: Thanks Björn Friedrich, I have edited this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The pronunciation of *Saite* is

> [ˈzaɪ̯tə] ([IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet))

[link](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Saite)

with a clear [t-sound](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/pronunciation/consonants-voiced-unvoiced/) like in "ten".

**Edit, because Uwe made a good point**

Looking at the plural form "Saiten" it's getting interesting. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Saiten) says it's pronounced

> [ˈzaɪ̯tn̩]

while the homophone "[Seiten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Seiten)" can be pronounced

> [ˈzaɪ̯tən] or [ˈzaɪ̯tn̩] as well

with the first one pronounced like the example at [forvo](https://de.forvo.com/search/saiten/) with a hard t-sound and the second one with a less clear t-sound and an omitted ə, which may be the reason for your question. Take a look at these [examples](https://de.forvo.com/search/seiten/) for different pronounciations of "Seiten".

So ... how does one pronounce Saiten? From my point of view it's possible to use both versions as well: [ˈzaɪ̯tən] and [ˈzaɪ̯tn̩], even if Wiktionary says it's just the second one.

Or as you say with a

> clear 't' sound with my tongue [or] a sort of vague 't' sound with the back of my throat

Comment: The OP asked about "Saiten", not about "Saite".  In the former, the "ə" may be zero-reduced, that is, /zaɪ̯tn̩/, and then the t-sound can be a lot less clear than in /zaɪ̯tə/. Compare https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/aussprache-von-wollen/48797, which describes a similar phenomenon.

Comment: @Uwe You are right. As Saiten & Seiten are similar in pronounciation we can look at these [examples on forvo](https://de.forvo.com/search/seiten/) for Seiten. They sound like Sei-ten, Sei-tn or Seit-n. I also have to think of the [Seitenbacher-commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt1w9nA6b5U).

Answer (score 1):

In German, the [t-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization) you often hear in varieties of British English is rare, where a word such as “Britain” would be pronounced as [ˈbɹɪʔn̩]. Instead, a [nasal release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_release) is more common, so «Saiten» would be pronounced as [ˈz̥aɪtⁿn̩]. Glottalization and nasals release are quite similar, though, insofar as the stop is not released at its proper place, which would be the tip of the tongue in the case of a [t].

That being said, it is quite common in many regions of Germany that a /t/ after a diphthong or long vowel is lenited to a [d̥], so «Saite» (and «Seite») would be pronounced like «Seide». However, many people would be unaware of this or even deny it outright because the influence of the spelling makes them believe that the pronunciation is different even though it is really not. Also, you can expect that people make an effort to distinguish these words when asked to pronounce them in isolation even though they would pronounce them exactly the same in their normal speech.

Comment: Glottalization is not uncommon in the North. As a Southerner, I find it a bit grating, though ironically I sometimes do it myself nowadays :)